# Add to Map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

In groovy I've got the following...

```
    def response = [
        modifications: []
    ]
```

I want to add to this map dynamically so that it ends up like this....

```
    def response = [
        modifications: [
            userKnown :[
                type: 'Boolean',
                value: userKnown?.toBoolean()
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

I've tried to do that using this code below...

```
    if (userKnown){
        def userKnownVariable = [
            userKnown :[
                type: 'Boolean',
                value: userKnown?.toBoolean()
            ]
        ]
        response.modifications << userKnownVariable
    }
```

But I don't quite end up with what I'm after. Can someone help me with what I'm doing wrong.

thanks

Comment: You can achieve that with simply using java. create a map say x and put type and value in that map and add this in a list say userKnown and then create a map and add this userKnown in userKnownVariable. That's it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are mixing two things in given example. `modifications` in your map is type of `List` when you use `[]` and you expect to have a `Map` instead. To instantiate a map this way you have to use `[:]`

```
def response = [
    modifications: [:]
]

def userKnown = [
    userKnown: [
        type: 'Boolean',
        value: true
    ]    
]

response.modifications << userKnown

assert response == [modifications: [userKnown: [type: 'Boolean', value: true]]]
```

One thing worth mentioning. Consider using `List` in your example. Adding a new keys to a map may sound reasonable in some cases, although it has one significant issue - the order of every key in `modifications` is not deterministic, it depends on the map implementation (`HashMap`, `TreeMap` etc.). From business logic point of view it looks like you are trying to get an information about all modifications that were applied/added. `List` in this case would be a better option - you can track the order in which every modification were applied and if you are using this response on the frontend side - it will be easier to iterate over a list and display every result.